# Spring @Scheduled inject delay time

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a few methods annotated with

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 6000)
private void myScheduledMethod(){
//do something
}
```

I also have a set of properties files where I configure environment specific values. For testing purposes I'd like the value of the delay to be configurable, ideally through a property in a properties file.

Since the value of `fixedDelay` has to be a constant, I'm looking for a way to get this set from a properties file, but haven't found a way to do it yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got stuck on the same issues but the best way to solve this now would be:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${my.delay.property}")
public void myScheduledMethod(){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It would be good to have this option, but I think it does not exist (the annotation is class-level, while the value would be injected when an instance is created).

In order to make this configurable use the xml namespace `<task:`. Like the example from the [spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html):

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="someObject" method="someMethod" 
         fixed-delay="${configuredDelay}"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```